# Android Room with RxJava Observable<> as data type giving compilation error

Tags: observable, rx-java2, android-room

For below code i am getting this error:

Error:(26, 31) error: Not sure how to convert a Cursor to this method's return type

```
@Dao
public interface FriendsDao {

@Query("SELECT * FROM Friends")
Flowable<List<Friends>> getAllFriends();

@Query("select * from Friends")
Observable<List<Friends>> getAllFriendsExample();
```

}

Above if i remove  getAllFriendsExample() everything is working fine I dont get it why above code working for flowable but not for observable.
can any please help for above problem.

Thanks in adavance

Comment: Room only supports Flowable now...

Comment: thanks Samuel actually  i was implementing rxlogobservable for debugging purpose thats why i need to implement observable rather than flowable can u please suggest any debug tool for flowable.

Comment: @PoonamParth then use https://github.com/android10/frodo2 it supports `Flowable`

Comment: @LordRaydenMK  I tried it but getting this error  https://github.com/android10/frodo2/issues/1

Comment: @PoonamParth Room works with Flowable from RxJava2. Other than waiting for the library author to fix the issue in Frodo2 I don't think there is much you can do. RxJava1 reached end of life on March 31, 2018 so support for RxJava1 from Room is unlikely.

Comment: Thank you @LordRaydenMK for your response I will go with rxjava1 for time being

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the error because Room does not support the RxJava(1) `Observable` type.

For [observable queries](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/accessing-data#query-observable) Room supports `LiveData` and `Publisher` and `Flowable` from RxJava2.

Since you need this to use Frodo (from the comments) and Frodo2 has a bug your options are:

- wait for the library author to fix it
- put your DAO class behind a repository and convert the `Flowable` to RxJava1 `Observable` using [RxJava2Interop](https://github.com/akarnokd/RxJava2Interop) so you can use Frodo (v1)

Since RxJava 1 reached End of Live option 2 is not really recommended.